# Aerospike grouped cummulative insert

Tags: go, aerospike

I have an app which gets billions of hits per day. I use golang, aerospike to capture number of hits.When i try to insert this into aerospike ( mostly AddOP operation) aerospike hangs. It takes more than 10000ms for simple inserts during heavy load.

So is there a way i could capture these in Golang script or through some connector/app -> buffer them -> add them up  and do insert every 1 minute or so into aerospike?

I heard about kafka, is it a good option for aerospike?Are there better alternatives for my requirement?

Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: You use aerospike to store hits? Metrics? Aren't ClickHouse, InfluxDB and DalmatinerDB are for that?